# unable to remove symbolic links of rsync copy of /bin and /dev

Tags: bash, backup, rsync, symbolic-link, rm

I accidentally made a rsync copy of my root directory, "/" using the -a option, as follows:

```
user@mycomputer:~$ rsync -a / /backup-dir
user@mycomputer:~$ ls -l /backup-dir/
total 10102784
drwxrwxrwx 1 user nogroup         0 Feb  3 18:18 bin
drwxrwxrwx 1 user nogroup         0 Feb  3 18:21 dev
```

I am unable to delete /backup-dir/bin and /backup-dir/dev or any of the individual files within due to what I suspect to a problem with being unable to remove symlinks within those directories. (/backup-dir/bin shown below, same for /backup-dir/dev).

```
user@mycomputer:~$ sudo rm -rf /backup-dir/bin
rm: cannot remove ‘/backup-dir/bin’: Directory not empty
user@mycomputer:~$ ls -l /backup-dir/bin
total 16384
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 22 Feb  3 16:11 bzcmp -> bzdiff
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 22 Feb  3 16:11 bzegrep -> bzgrep
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 22 Feb  3 16:11 bzfgrep -> bzgrep
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 22 Feb  3 16:11 bzless -> bzmore
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 26 Feb  3 16:11 dnsdomainname -> hostname
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 26 Feb  3 16:11 domainname -> hostname
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 26 Feb  3 16:11 lessfile -> lesspipe
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 18 Feb  3 16:11 lsmod -> kmod
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 26 Feb  3 16:11 nisdomainname -> hostname
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 22 Feb  3 16:11 open -> openvt
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 18 Feb  3 16:11 rbash -> bash
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 18 Feb  3 16:11 rnano -> nano
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 18 Feb  3 16:11 sh -> dash
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 18 Feb  3 16:11 sh.distrib -> dash
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 24 Feb  3 16:11 static-sh -> busybox
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 26 Feb  3 16:11 ypdomainname -> hostname
user@mycomputer:~$ sudo rm /backup-dir/bin/bzcmp
user@mycomputer:~$ ls -l /backup-dir/bin
total 16384
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 22 Feb  3 16:11 bzcmp -> bzdiff
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 22 Feb  3 16:11 bzegrep -> bzgrep
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 22 Feb  3 16:11 bzfgrep -> bzgrep
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 22 Feb  3 16:11 bzless -> bzmore
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 26 Feb  3 16:11 dnsdomainname -> hostname
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 26 Feb  3 16:11 domainname -> hostname
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 26 Feb  3 16:11 lessfile -> lesspipe
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 18 Feb  3 16:11 lsmod -> kmod
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 26 Feb  3 16:11 nisdomainname -> hostname
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 22 Feb  3 16:11 open -> openvt
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 18 Feb  3 16:11 rbash -> bash
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 18 Feb  3 16:11 rnano -> nano
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 18 Feb  3 16:11 sh -> dash
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 18 Feb  3 16:11 sh.distrib -> dash
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 24 Feb  3 16:11 static-sh -> busybox
lr-xr-xr-x 1 user root 26 Feb  3 16:11 ypdomainname -> hostname
```

I was also unable to chmod permissions within /backup-dir/bin, in case that matters.

UPDATE:
This leads me in the right direction: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33594

```
user@mycomputer:~$ sudo strace rm -f /backup-dir/bin/bzcmp
... (long message, which includes the following)...
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "bin/bzcmp", 0)      = 0
```

The attempts to `unlink` the files are unsuccessful. The link above suggests deleting by inode.  However, I want to preserve the inodes for the original files located in /bin. I only want to remove the symbolic links in order to remove /backup-dir/bin/ and /backup-dir/dev/.

Suggestions for how to remove /backup-dir/bin and /backup-dir/dev are appreciated.

Comment: Rsync created it, maybe rsync can delete it too:   `mkdir empty; rsync -a --delete empty/. /backup-dir/bin/.` and execute as the same user as the one that created it.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else worked (strange) I suggest you to use again `rsync`

```
mkdir empty_dir
sudo rsync -a --delete empty_dir/    /backup-dir/bin/
```

Source:

- [Efficiently delete large directory containing thousands of files.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79656/66388)

Comment: +1 for the references.  Unsuccessful, however.  For /backup-dir/bin/, same as OP, symlinks still persist, unable to delete due to directory not empty.  For /backup-dir/dev/, 
    `cannot delete non-empty directory: snd/by-path`
    `cannot delete non-empty directory: <others>  <-- emphasis mine`